# Magento reindex url_rewrite is not working anymore

Tags: php, magento, url-rewriting, reindex

I’m stuck with the following issue in a live Magento store.

After i've created new categories for one of my 2 stores (multistore setup), i’m not able to reindex the URL rewrites. I’ve already emptied the core_url_rewrite table in the database, cleared the var/locks folder and tried to reindex, but it did’nt make any difference.

When i take a look at the exeption.log, it gives the following exception.

```
2013-12-10T11:06:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction 
Trace: #0 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) 
#1 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) 
#2 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) 
#3 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(’DELETE FROM `ma...’, Array) 
#4 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query(’DELETE FROM `ma...’, Array) 
#5 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(661): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(’DELETE FROM `ma...’) 
#6 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Url.php(1135): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->delete(’magcore_url_rew...’, Array) 
#7 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Url.php(1194): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url->clearStoreCategoriesInvalidRewrites(’1’) 
#8 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(596): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url->clearStoreInvalidRewrites(’1’) 
#9 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(253): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->clearStoreInvalidRewrites(’1’) 
#10 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(248): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites(’1’) 
#11 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Url.php(257): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites() 
#12 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url->reindexAll() 
#13 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll() 
#14 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Index/controllers/Adminhtml/ProcessController.php(127): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything() 
#15 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction() 
#16 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch(’reindexProcess’) 
#17 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) 
#18 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() 
#19 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 
#20 /home/users/hertwftp/hertog-hengelsport.nl/index.php(91): Mage::run(’hs’, ‘store’) 
#21 {main}
```

I hope someone can point me to the right solution, i’m quite desperate as it comes to this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this issue by installing an extension that fastened the index process [Extension](http://www.dnd.fr/2012/09/magento-patch-how-to-optimize-re-index-processing-time-for-url-rewrite/)
I have 17k products in my shop and i suspect that was the problem.

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Try truncating all tables starting with log

```
TRUNCATE `log_customer`;
TRUNCATE `log_quote`;
TRUNCATE `log_summary`;
TRUNCATE `log_summary_type`;
TRUNCATE `log_url`;
TRUNCATE `log_url_info`;
TRUNCATE `log_visitor`;
TRUNCATE `log_visitor_info`;
```

Also clear all cache, locks, session from the folders and try running site again.

Also you can check this for a method _replace

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/260/price-re-index-causes-db-deadlocks-during-checkout

Comment: Unfortunately, it did'nt work. The CORE_URL_REWRITE table just stays empty. The indexing process still gives the same exception.